# Recoding percentiles: function instead of for-loop

Tags: r, for-loop, dataframe, percentile

I have not been able to find the answer to my question anywhere, so here goes:

I would like to know how to do a for loop with the variable names in a dataframe.

```
for ( EACH VARIABLE in DATAFRAME){
    operation
    }
```

I have tried different varieties of `i in names(df)` etc, no success.

What I want to do is simple. I want to recode variables: the upper Xth percentile = 1, rest = 0. I have been able to do this as follows:

```
   j <- ntile (df$variable, 100)
   newdf$variable_percentile <-j
   newdf$variable_binomial <- 0
   newdf$variable_binomial[j>x] <-1
```

I would appreciate help with the loop for this, or a way to do this easier. Perhaps with a function and apply?

Yours sincerely,
Lian

Answer (score 0, accepted):

this code was provided to me by Rob Wanders

```
indicator <- function(variable, quantile) {
    return(.bincode(variable,breaks=c(0,quantile(variable,probs=quantile[[1]],max(variable)),include.lowest=TRUE)-1)
}
```

indicator(data,90) will now code the highest 10 percent as 1 and the rest as 0